# flutter ad's only display in test mode

Tags: flutter

I try to implement ad mob package in my flutter app. I have create my admob account, I choose reward ad, I have my Id bloc and my appId, I have add my google-services.json in the app folder,I have completed the manifest.

My problem is when I use

```
.load(adUnitId: RewardedVideoAd.testAdUnitId, targetingInfo: targetingInfo)
```

It's OK I can see video ad after press button, but it's not my unitID

If I use my UnitID like that

```
.load(adUnitId:"ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx", targetingInfo: targetingInfo)
```

I have no video ad after press button
I have this error

```
 error in showing ad: PlatformException(ad_not_loaded, show failed for rewarded video, no ad was loaded, null)
```

I have since long time a bug with  release mode, so I launch only in debug mode, it can be the source of my problem ?

Are there a delay of use after creation of admob account or bloc ? 
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ads show when u publish your app in the store so if the test ads work's fin than your ads work perfact

Comment: doesn't it show in the internal testing part (in the play console) even?